# How do I check if a view's model is correct?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an "Index" controller method which returns a view with a Model that is a `List<WhatsNew>`. I am trying to validate this method in a unit test but it gives me an error as it is expecting a string.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("Index", GetWhatsNew());
}

public List<WhatsNew> GetWhatsNew()
{
   WCMSDataContext wcmsContext = new WCMSDataContext();

   return (from p in wcmsContext.WhatsNews select p).ToList();
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Validate_Index_IList_WhatsNew_AS_Model()
{
    AppItemController controller = new AppItemController();  

    // Act
    var result = controller.Index();

    // Assert
    var model = ((ViewResult)result).Model as List<WhatsNew>;

    Assert.AreEqual("Index",  model.ToList());
}
```

**Error**

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Index (System.String)>. Actual:  <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WCMS.WhatsNew]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a `string` "Index" with a `List<WhatsNew>`:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Index",  model.ToList());
```

What exactly are you expecting to happen here?

You can check the contents of the model:

```
Assert.AreEqual(someValue, model.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(someOtherValue, model[0].SomeProperty);
```

You can also check the right page is being returned in the action:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Index", ((ViewResult)result).ViewName);
```

At the moment, you seem to be trying to mix the two...

You may want to have a read of something like [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs) as a basic introduction to checking your controllers.

Comment: I want to check whether the correct Model is passed to this view or not. The Index view is currently expecting List<WhatsNew> and i want to ensure if its getting the correct model or not.

Comment: @HammadBukhari That's what the middle asserts in my answer is addressing... checking the number of items in the list, then validating each item has the correct value.  If that doesn't answer your question, then you need to include more information about what you need,  possibly including information about the model for example so I don't need to make up names like 'SomeProperty'...  You may also need to look into stubbing your datacontext if it's hitting a database, so that it doesn't during unit testing, but that's a different question...